# MessageBodyReader not found for media

Tags: java, xml, json

im trying to retrieve a get response from IMDB.com's or AnimeNewsNetwork's APIs using java EE

i started hacking this guy's really nice example of connecting to a weather website API (had to install vaadin view framework)

it looks like i've made some progress (especially in understanding what's going on) but im at a problem for a long time now (3 hours although a lot of that was failing to get github to work....)

i am getting, when i try to run the application:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html; charset=utf-8, type=class org.example.domain.ForecastResponse, genericType=class org.example.domain.ForecastResponse.
```

i pasted

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
<version>2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

into the pom thing and i found a button in netbeans that "checks for problems" then it automatically updated my project with dependencies which took ages and was rather shocking and i thought it'd work then

then i tried changing .request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML) back and forth to APPLICATION_JSON (imdb defaults to json) and TEXT_HTML_TYPE or whatever i tried.

lastly i tried changing my query input from a correct movie ID tt1285016 to an incorrect one to see if that would give a different result when it only returns 2 parameters instead of 20. this brings me to the question: how does my application know how to map the response from the API to the class? a normal response is a JSON string that has 20 fields so how does my application know where to put them? maybe this is the missing link. i just changed the movie classes attributes to Response and Error to match the 2 returns from sending an incorrect movie ID to the API but still same problem

(hours later): tried to run using the anime news network's API instead and getting similar error which differs in saying "messagbodyreader not found" for text/xml instead of text/html...

i've also tried adding a few more things to the pom file from jersey dependencies document and well one of them makes my project stop deploying even after i delete and rebuild it so i've had fun with that.

below i will paste the code i am using. please note i am just hacking this guy's example up trying to get my basic functionality working and avoiding changing anything else so i can understand what i'm supposed to do, before rewriting it from scratch just to prototype before beginning to plan the actual project!! i have a lot more tutorials/examples to look at in the future so don't worry about my code other than the problem i'm stuck on :/

this is the "view" java class that uses vaadin
VaadinUI.java

```
package org.example;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.cdi.CDIUI;
import com.vaadin.data.Property;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.NativeSelect;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.vaadin.maddon.label.Header;
import org.vaadin.maddon.layouts.MVerticalLayout;


/**
 * A simple example how to consume REST apis with JAX-RS and display that in 
 * a Vaadin UI.
 */
@CDIUI("")
@Theme("valo")
public class VaadinUI extends UI {

    @Inject
    JsonService service;
    ForecastDisplay display = new ForecastDisplay();
    NativeSelect citySelector = new NativeSelect("Choose city");

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

//        citySelector.addItems("tt1285016","tt1285016");
//        citySelector.addValueChangeListener(this::changeCity);
//        citySelector.setValue("tt1285016");

        setContent(new MVerticalLayout(
                        new Header("Simple REST weather"),
                        display));

                display.setForecast(service.fetchMovie());


    }




////        display.setForecast(service.getForecast(citySelector.getValue().toString()));
//    }

}
```

JsonService.java

```
package org.example;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.cdi.CDIUI;
import com.vaadin.data.Property;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.NativeSelect;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.vaadin.maddon.label.Header;
import org.vaadin.maddon.layouts.MVerticalLayout;


/**
 * A simple example how to consume REST apis with JAX-RS and display that in 
 * a Vaadin UI.
 */
@CDIUI("")
@Theme("valo")
public class VaadinUI extends UI {

    @Inject
    JsonService service;
    ForecastDisplay display = new ForecastDisplay();
    NativeSelect citySelector = new NativeSelect("Choose city");

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

//        citySelector.addItems("tt1285016","tt1285016");
//        citySelector.addValueChangeListener(this::changeCity);
//        citySelector.setValue("tt1285016");

        setContent(new MVerticalLayout(
                        new Header("Simple REST weather"),
                        display));

                display.setForecast(service.fetchMovie());


    }




////        display.setForecast(service.getForecast(citySelector.getValue().toString()));
//    }

}
```

ForecastDisplay.java

```
package org.example;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import org.example.domain.Forecast;
import org.example.domain.ForecastResponse;
import org.vaadin.maddon.label.Header;
import org.vaadin.maddon.label.RichText;
import org.vaadin.maddon.layouts.MVerticalLayout;


/**
 *
 * @author Matti Tahvonen <matti@vaadin.com>
 */
public class ForecastDisplay extends MVerticalLayout {

    String mainTemplate = "Tomorrow in there will be ";


    public ForecastDisplay() {
    }

    public void setForecast(ForecastResponse fr) {

//        removeAllComponents();
        removeAllComponents();
        addComponents(
                new Header(String.format(mainTemplate,fr.getMovie().getMovieInfo(),
                        fr.getMovie().getMovieInfo()))
        );

//        
//        for (Forecast f : fr.getList()) {
//            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
//            Date date = cal.getTime();
//            Double temperature = f.getTemp().getDay();
//            String desc = f.getWeather().get(0).getDescription();
//            String md = String.format(detailTemplate, date, temperature, desc);
//            addComponent(new RichText().withMarkDown(md));
        }
    }
```

ForecastResponse.java class

```
package org.example.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ForecastResponse {



//    private String cod;
//    private Double message;
//    private City city;
//    private Integer cnt;
//    private java.util.List<Forecast> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private Movie movie;
//
//    public String getCod() {
//        return cod;
//    }
//
//    public void setCod(String cod) {
//        this.cod = cod;
//    }
//
//    public Double getMessage() {
//        return message;
//    }
//
//    public void setMessage(Double message) {
//        this.message = message;
//    }
//
//    public City getCity() {
//        return city;
//    }
//
//    public void setCity(City city) {
//        this.city = city;
//    }

    public Movie getMovie()
    {
        return movie;

    }

        public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }
//
//    public Integer getCnt() {
//        return cnt;
//    }
//
//    public void setCnt(Integer cnt) {
//        this.cnt = cnt;
//    }
//
//    public java.util.List<Forecast> getList() {
//        return list;
//    }
//
//    public void setList(java.util.List<Forecast> list) {
//        this.list = list;
//    }

}
```

Movie.java class

```
package org.example.domain;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;

public class Movie {


    private String Response;
    private String Error;


    public String getMovieInfo() {
        return Response;
    }

    public void setMovieInfo(String name) {
        this.Response = Response;
    }


    public String getMovieInfo2() {
        return Error;
    }

    public void setMovieInfo2(String name) {
        this.Error = Error;
    }
}
```

the guy's project before i cut it up (you need vaadin plugin to run it)
https://github.com/mstahv/consuming-rest-apis

just to reiterate i am getting

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html; charset=utf-8, type=class org.example.domain.ForecastResponse, genericType=class org.example.domain.ForecastResponse.
```

when i try to run the application and have tried a number of solutions... but i think its because of something i changed because i had no problems getting the guy's original files to run

i have uploaded my current version to mirrorcreator (can't get git to work...sigh) : https://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/KQF7SBBH/restapiexampletest1zip._links

thankyou for reading . i have searched google a lot but not able to fix it using the suggestions like change the poms file or whatever....

Comment: edit: i updated the part "new Header(String.format(mainTemplate,fr.getMovie().getMovieInfo(),
                        fr.getMovie().getMovieInfo()))" to be correct, forgot to edit that in my original post. but nothing ive done changes this problem. 
ive tried to run using the anime news network's API instead of IMDB and getting similar error which differs in saying "messagbodyreader not found" for text/xml instead of text/html

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but you should check the API and see what return types it produces. If it produces JSON as a type, then you should set the `Accept` header in your request to `application/json`. I don't use vaadin, so I can't really help further, besides I don't even see any client code, when somewhere (maybe under the hood) it seems Jersey client is being used. But what is most likely happening is the url your requesting return xml-/-html, and you are trying to unmarshal it to your Java object, which won't work

Comment: thankyou for the response. i have definitely been wondering on and off how the response is supposed to be parsed into my object. it seems like i am parsing it into Forecastresponse then Movie but there are only 2 slots for data in Movie. i tried sending a request to IMDB for an invalid movie ID because this returns 2 segments of JSON (actually the warning is for "text/html" for IMDB which is weird...) but this doesnt change my error. thanks again, i will look at other example tomorrow and will hopefully gain understanding of how the data is received by the classes.